# Script works only on Chrome and Firefox Desktop, and not works on Safari and any mobile browser

Tags: javascript

I can't understand why this script works only on Chrome and Firefox on Desktop, and not works on Safari Desktop and any mobile browser.

```
<span style="font-size:1.4rem;margin:0 .5rem;"><span id="days"></span> Days</span>
<span style="font-size:1.4rem;margin:0 .5rem;"><span id="hours"></span> Hours</span>
<span style="font-size:1.4rem;margin:0 .5rem;"><span id="minutes"></span> Minutes</span>
<span style="font-size:1.4rem;margin:0 .5rem;"><span id="seconds"></span> Seconds</span>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var second = 1000;
    var minute = second * 60;
    var hour = minute * 60;
    var day = hour * 24;

    var countDown = new Date('Apr 20, 2021 24:00:00').getTime();

    var x = setInterval(function () {

        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDown - now;

        document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / day),
        document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor(distance % day / hour),
        document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor(distance % hour / minute),
        document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor(distance % minute / second);
    }, second);

</script>
```

I've checked all the incompatibilities but I don't seem to see any.
Returned to me alloways `NaN` even if I use `Number(...)`

I just can't understand.

Comment: I suppose the script is cached in the mobile browsers, as your script [seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/gzceoaj3/show) in mobile browsers too. Not related to the question, but don't use comma to separate statements, semicolon is for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu, I'm not clear what happens, you say it is stored so the update does not work? I have tried from different devices and it is always the same. Could it be the server?

Comment: Specifically phones are aggressively caching content. You can prevent caching by sending [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) header from your server. Make also sure, that the Date object is correctly constructed, use the parameter based [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#syntax) (`new Date(year, monthIndex, day, hours, minutes)`) to guarantee a succesful construction in every environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari is a lot more strict on date formats.

I would suggest changing the format of your data string or manipulating it with Regex and so forth but it all gets a bit messy. One is assuming all your date data is going to be consistent?!

Example: https://codepen.io/alexpetergill/pen/39b775983b851e8fa14f1e548252d810

Just tested this on Big Sur / Safari 14

```
var months = {
  'Jan' : '01',
  'Feb' : '02',
  'Mar' : '03',
  'Apr' : '04',
  'May' : '05',
  'Jun' : '06',
  'Jul' : '07',
  'Aug' : '08',
  'Sep' : '09',
  'Oct' : '10',
  'Nov' : '11',
  'Dec' : '12'
}
  
function parseDate(s) {
  var dateTime = s.split(' ');
  var time = dateTime.pop();
  var day = dateTime[1].replace(/[, ]+/g, ' ').trim();
  var month = months[dateTime[0]];
  var year = dateTime[2];
  var date = new Date(year + '-' + month + '-' + day).toISOString().split('T')[0]
  return Date.parse(date + 'T' + time) // 2021-04-20T24:00:00
}
  
var countDown = parseDate('Apr 20, 2021 24:00:00');
```

The output of `parseDate()` is loosely based on the ECMAScript specification https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-date-time-string-format

> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based
> upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 calendar date extended format.
> The format is as follows: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

Comment: Thank you @Alex-gill, yes this works. So the problem was in the formatting of the date and its transformation into number. I didn't know about these formatting problems. Thanks so much!

Comment: good job (+1), I learned something more! (I integrated your answer into mine, with some personal improvements)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect a problem due to your **commas** at the end some calculations - which are not tolerated on mobile devices?

you have
`...  Math.floor(distance / day),`
`... Math.floor(distance % day / hour),` .

I also think using `Date.parse()` is better **[Alex Gill] & [Teemu] messages

you should also avoid using `var` and replace them with `let` for local variables, otherwise `const`

otherwise, I'll code it like this:

```js
const
    twoDigits = s => (s.length > 2) ? `0${s}` : s
  , months = 
      { Jan: '01', Feb: '02', Mar: '03', Apr: '04', May: '05', Jun: '06'
      , Jul: '07', Aug: '08', Sep: '09', Oct: '10', Nov: '11', Dec: '12'
      } 
  , getDateN = sDateMdYt =>  // copied from Alex Gill answer
      {
      let [mm,dd,yy,tim] = sDateMdYt.split(/,\s|\s/)
      return Date.parse(`${yy}-${months[mm]}-${twoDigits(dd)}T${tim}`) 
      }
  , tims = document.querySelectorAll('#timer > span')
  , cuts = [60,60,24].reduce((t,v,i)=>
      {
      t.push(v*t[i])
      return t
      },[1000]).reverse()
  , countDown = getDateN('Apr 22, 2021 17:23:00')  // target DateTime!!
  ;
var sIref = setInterval(()=>
      {
      let diff = countDown - (new Date().getTime())
      if (diff < 0) 
        {
        clearInterval(sIref)
        return 
        }
      tims.forEach((sp,i)=>
        {
        let count = Math.floor(diff / cuts[i])
        diff -= count * cuts[i]
        sp.textContent = count
        })
      }, 250)
```

```css
p    { font-size:1.4rem; }
span { padding:0 .3rem 0 1rem;  }
```

```html
<p id="timer">
  <span></span>Days
  <span></span>Hours
  <span></span>Minutes
  <span></span>Seconds
</p>
```

Comment: Comma separated statements are not a syntax error (in this case), and they [seem to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/gzceoaj3/1/show) in mobile browsers too. I suppose `countDown` becomes `Invalid date` in some browsers because of the format of the date string in the parameter for `Date`.

Comment: @Teemu I still have a doubt about the commas, and anyway they remain inadequate here. And you are also right, using `Date.parse()` would be better, I changed my code

Comment: Thank you @MisterJojo, Sure your code is much cleaner! But this not work on safari, I just try on my website and also open this link inside Safari and doesn't work.

Comment: @MarcoRomano I changed my code to integrate **Alex Gill** work, he deserve your validation. ;)